# How to change type of class C#

Tags: c#, class, eventargs

I have this class in C# that uses MouseEventArgs and I want to call that function and makes it work without using MouseEventArgs. Any Ideas how can I do that?

```
private void SpatialControl_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _camChanged = false;
        DrawingControl.Viewport.Camera.Changed += Camera_Changed;
        DrawingControl.ZoomSelected();
        DrawingControl.Viewport.Camera.Changed -= Camera_Changed;
        if (!_camChanged)
            DrawingControl.ClipBaseSelected(0.15);
    }
```

and I also want to add this

```
DrawingControl.Viewport.Camera.Position = new Point3D(100, 100, 1);
DrawingControl.Viewport.SetView(new Point3D(-1,-1,-1), new Vector3D(1,1,1), new Vector3D(1,2,1),5);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make it work without using MouseButtonEventArgs"?  That's an event handler, and it's invoked by a mouse event.  (Specifically a double-click.)  Why wouldn't there be MouseButtonEventArgs in a mouse event?  Also, that code doesn't *do* anything with the MouseButtonEventArgs it's given, so in what way does it not work?

Comment: what is the purpose of removing MouseButtonEventArgs ?

Comment: So my project is about doing anything automatically, like I want to Display a model, set its initial position and then rotate the model just by clicking "Run". I don't want any human interaction after that. But all the examples that I found are by using MouseEventArgs or buttons to Rotate the model, so I want to change those functions and make them work with out the Event Args. So this class is just an example because I can't post all of my project because it is Huuuuuuuuuuuuuge

Comment: you should Write your purpose in your question too. so people can help you.anyway. You must add click even for button `Run` and do everything inside that method. this happens without human interaction. where is the confusion?

Comment: I don't want to have any buttons and when I say Run, I mean Debugging the project.

Comment: If you mean you want to do it when app starts then You have Load event for your form.Just click in your main form then set the Load event for it.

Comment: Also you should mention other people when you write comment. or they will not get notify and may not answer you forever. see [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: @PantelitsaMavrovounioti Why would you use another function when you can just ignore the parameter in the function body?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thanks for your help and sorry for not being specific and not tagging people its because I am new in this.

Comment: @ArthurRey as I mentioned before my project is Huge so I can't explain and show exactly what I want and what I do, but my functions doesn't work in my main project (where "private void SpatialControl_MouseDoubleClick" is)  so I have to add a new function at the point after the model is loaded. I Don't know if you guys understand what I am saying and I am so sorry if I am not being specific but it is complicated but thanks for help anyway :)

Comment: So following @Jashaszun answer I just removed the parameters and called the function somewhere else and it work. I was just calling it in a wrong class.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the handled method from another method.

```
public void Mymethod()
{
   // Callind the event
   SpatialControl_MouseDoubleClick(new object(), new MouseButtonEventArgs()) 
   // Executing other code.
   DrawingControl.Viewport.Camera.Position = new Point3D(100, 100, 1);
   DrawingControl.Viewport.SetView(new Point3D(-1,-1,-1), new Vector3D(1,1,1), new Vector3D(1,2,1),5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the first thing (call that function without using `MouseButtonEventArgs`) by simply making another function that `SpatialControl_MouseDoubleClick` calls:

```
private void spatialControl_DoubleClick()
{
    _camChanged = false;
    DrawingControl.Viewport.Camera.Changed += Camera_Changed;
    DrawingControl.ZoomSelected();
    DrawingControl.Viewport.Camera.Changed -= Camera_Changed;
    if (!_camChanged)
        DrawingControl.ClipBaseSelected(0.15);
    DrawingControl.Viewport.Camera.Position = new Point3D(100, 100, 1);
    DrawingControl.Viewport.SetView(new Point3D(-1,-1,-1), new Vector3D(1,1,1), new Vector3D(1,2,1),5);
}
private void SpatialControl_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    spatialControl_DoubleClick();
}
```

Alternatively, you can keep your `SpatialControl_MouseDoubleClick` function, remove its parameters, and then go to your `[FormName].Designer.cs` file, find the

```
`this.[control-name].MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.SpatialControl_MouseDoubleClick);
```

line and change it to

```
this.[control-name].MouseDoubleClick += (sender, e) => this.SpatialControl_MouseDoubleClick();
```

Then, the code in your `[FormName].cs` file will look like this:

```
private void SpatialControl_MouseDoubleClick()
{
    _camChanged = false;
    DrawingControl.Viewport.Camera.Changed += Camera_Changed;
    DrawingControl.ZoomSelected();
    DrawingControl.Viewport.Camera.Changed -= Camera_Changed;
    if (!_camChanged)
        DrawingControl.ClipBaseSelected(0.15);
    DrawingControl.Viewport.Camera.Position = new Point3D(100, 100, 1);
    DrawingControl.Viewport.SetView(new Point3D(-1,-1,-1), new Vector3D(1,1,1), new Vector3D(1,2,1),5);
}
```

Comment: That worked thanks. I did removed the parameters and called the function somewhere else and it worked. Thank you :)

Comment: @PantelitsaMavrovounioti Consider upvoting and/or marking as answer then. Other people in the future can then look and see that my answer is correct :).

Comment: I did vote up but I only have 11 reputations so it says that my vote will be shown after I collect 15